# Удаленное устройство для дебага в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, telnet, android-adb

На удаленной машине есть adb и он подключен к телевизору(на андроид) по wifi. Цель получить возможность в андроид студио на моей машине видеть этот телевизор. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking Есть такая информация, там говорится что именно эмуляторы андроид и само устройство на котором запущен эмулятор находятся в разных подсетях(или еще как-то) и не видят друг друга. То есть мне мало получить доступ к удаленной машине, мне нужен доступ к эмулятору . И для этого можно использовать и adb , там есть возможность проброса портов или telnet. Я решил попробовать через telnet так как это более гибкое решение, как мне показалось. Но меня смущает то, что это для доступа к удаленному эмулятору. А как насчет удаленного реального девайса?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245597/how-can-i-deploy-and-execute-an-application-on-a-device-connected-to-a-remote-sy   Тут есть информация, но у меня не вышло подключиться и я не совсем уверен можно ли это сделать для устройства находящегося в другой сети

Comment: Кажется для этого вопроса ещё важно , какую используют на удаленной машине. Если там сидят через мобильную связь, то их ip находятся, так сказать в отдельной зоне за межсетевым экраном и ip не публичный, как нам может показаться.